# jQuery UI draggable and sortable - hard to sort

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

```
$("#source li").draggable({
    appendTo: "#destination",
    helper: "clone",
    connectToSortable: "#destination",
    containment: "document"
});

$("#destination").sortable({
    items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
    connectWith: "li",
    placeholder: "dragging-placeholder",
    sort: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
    },
    over: function() {
        $(".placeholder").hide();
    },
    out: function() {
        if ($(this).children(":not(.placeholder)").length === 0) {
            $(".placeholder").show();
        }
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9FK5/7/

When I drag a few boxes from the source UL to the target, they become very hard to sort, especially when trying to move to the beginning. Regular sorting works with the same CSS.

I know it's a common problem, but none of the solutions worked in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your [`tolerance`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-tolerance) option and set it to `pointer`.

> Specifies which mode to use for testing whether the item being moved
>   is hovering over another item. Possible values:
>
> - "intersect": The item overlaps the other item by at least 50%.
> - "pointer": The mouse pointer overlaps the other item.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Fs772/

Comment: Thanks! That's a big improvement. It still lags at times (ie. appears to skip some positions), but no one expects these things to be perfect.